# Can I throw a FileNotFoundException for any method, or is it only for main method?

Tags: java

I have a program that is suppose to save information to a file using File IO when the user presses the 'x' at the top of the GUI, but when I put the `throws FileNotFoundException` in the main method, it won't compile without errors.

My code for that section is this:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {




File myFile = new java.io.File("GuidanceAppt.txt");
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(myFile);
for (int i=0;i!=1000;i++){
    output.println(studentNum[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + time + " " + counselor + " ");

}


}
```

Am I able to do add the throw at the top?

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)throws FileNotFoundException {




File myFile = new java.io.File("GuidanceAppt.txt");
PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(myFile);
for (int i=0;i!=1000;i++){
    output.println(studentNum[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + time + " " + counselor + " ");

}

}
```

Comment: You really need to find a good tutorial on Java exceptions and study it.  The `throws` statement is only a relatively small part of the stuff you need to understand.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that but you will eventually have to deal with the exception. If you don't, then while it is running it may exit unhappily.

One way is to surround with a [try and catch block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html). And tell the user about the file not existing, or to create it.

Answer (score 0):

If your class implements `WindowListener`, you will not be able to add `throws FileNotFoundException` at the top because your class will not correctly override the `windowClosing` method. What you need to do instead is use a try-catch block around the methods that can throw a `FileNotFoundException`:

```
try {
    File myFile = new java.io.File("GuidanceAppt.txt");
    PrintWriter output = new PrintWriter(myFile);
    for (int i=0;i!=1000;i++){
        output.println(studentNum[i] + " " + name[i] + " " + time + " " + counselor + " ");
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

A good way to check if you're correctly overriding methods is to use the `@Override` annotation, which is place before a method:

```
@Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) 
    throws FileNotFoundException { // compilation error

@Override public void windowClosing(WindowEvent ev) {
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are overriding a method in a superclass (like `WindowAdapter`) or implementing a method in an interface (like `WindowListener`) then your override can only declare thrown exceptions which the superclass/interface method also declares.

Since `windowClosing` in `WindowListener` declares no exceptions, your override isn't allowed to declare any exceptions either.

Methods that are *not* overrides or interface implementations can throw whichever exceptions you want.